# Centering div items when screen is under 768px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Issue:** My product grid won't center under 576px.

**Question:** How can I create the css so the products center under 576px

I would like for when the screen size is under 768 for the products to be centered.  This is mainly for mobile devises because i have the images resized to be smaller so 2 can fit per row but they are aligned to the left a bit.

**This is the html:**

```
<div class="right">
   <div class="center">
      <h1>Talent</h1>
   </div>    
   <div class="product-">
      <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
        <div class="image-circle">
            <div class="listing-page-images" id="listing-image-resize">
                <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image_url(:listing_index_4), id: "listing-image-resize-2"), listing, id: "listing-image-resize", data: {id: listing.id, name: listing.name} %>
            </div>
            <div class="text-over">
               <p><%= link_to listing.user.name, listing, id: "" %></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.right {
  flex: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif ;
  font-weight: 600 ;
}

 .product- {
   padding-top: 30px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
   #listing-image-resize {
     width:  100px !important;
     height:  150px !important;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
   }
   #listing-image-resize-2 {
     position: absolute;
     width:  100px !important;
     height:  150px !important;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
   }

 }
```

***One thing I have noticed*** is that from 768px to 576px, the products are centered on the page - with and without my @media 576px css rule.

I am using bootstrap 4 and I'm assuming it does something automatically but I haven't found any answers to what's happening within that screen size range to center everything.

This is all contained within a body tag that has no @media css rules.

Comment: If you need to center items inside .product- add align-items: center; and justify- content: center; if you need to center .product- add margin-left: auto; and margin- right: auto;

Comment: Thats it! if you want them points ill green check you if you make a post! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to center items inside .product- then add:

```
.product- {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  //Add This
  align-items: center;
  justify- content: center;
}
```

if you need to center .product- then add:

```
.product- {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  //Add This
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

  align-items: center;
  justify- content: center;
}
```